# Starting from one git repository and committing to another

Tags: git

Suppose I want to pull a framework and several packages from multiple repositories as my coding starting point, work on the code for my project, then commit the changes to a new repository. What would be the git process for doing this?

Comment: The answer depends heavily on the language and framework that you want to use. Many frameworks come with a recommended workflow. Many languages have dependency management tools. Doing this yourself at the version control level should be a last resort.

Comment: Do you want to extend / base on one of the project? Do you want to merge two projects into a new one? Or do the other repositories only contain code you'd like to use in your project? If your question is related to the latter, I go with Chris: don't do this on VCS level.

Comment: PHP project using a starter package based on the Laravel framework. Really, I will probably only use that as the base and use composer to import every other dependency as I've been doing. I'm toying with the idea of doing a git clone for the starting code instead of downloading a zip so I can possibly merge updates from that starting code as bug fixes arise so my project benefits. I just don't know if that approach is feasible or more trouble than it is worth.

Answer (score 1):

Clone the repositories you want to use code from to local projects.  Create a new project or pick one of these projects to be your new project, and move the code from the the other projects to your new project.  Commit the code in your new project.  If desired, create an upstream in Github for your new project and push your code there.

Comment: I actually had this same question earlier today. 
When you say "create a new project", are you saying that you should make a new directory containing all the projects, do a `git init` in this directory, and then do a `git remote add` for the the new repo?